# Spring MVC Validation for list and reporting the invalid value

Tags: spring, validation, spring-mvc, hibernate-validator, spring-validator

I have a list of strings which should be of a specific format. I need to return the error message with the strings which are not of the format specified. How to do this with spring validation(I am using the hibernate validator). 
The annotation:

```
@Documented
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target({FIELD, METHOD})
@Constraint(validatedBy = HostsValidator.class)
public @interface HostsConstraint {
    String message();

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

The implementation:

```
public class HostsValidator implements ConstraintValidator<HostsConstraint, List<String>>{

    @Override
    public void initialize(OriginHostsConstraint constraintAnnotation) {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(List<String> strings, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        for (String s : strings) {
            if (!s.matches("[0-9]+") {
                //How do I say: Invalid string <s> ?
                return false;
            }
        }

    }

}
```

The usage:

```
public class Test {

    @HostsConstraint(message="Invalid string ")
    private List<String> hosts;

}
```

Using `validatedValue` will give the entire list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use JSR 380 validation, it allows container element constraints.

Here is a link to the container element section in the [Hibernate Validator 6.0.6.FINAL Document](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#container-element-constraints)

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a solution but it is coupled to hibernate validator. May be it is even a hacky implementation.

The usage:

```
public class Test {

    @HostsConstraint(message="Invalid string : ${invalidStr}")
    private List<String> hosts;

}
```

The implementation

```
public class HostsValidator implements ConstraintValidator<HostsConstraint, List<String>>{

    @Override
    public void initialize(OriginHostsConstraint constraintAnnotation) {}

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(List<String> strings, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        for (String s : strings) {
            if (!s.matches("[0-9]+") {
                ConstraintValidatorContextImpl contextImpl =
                    (ConstraintValidatorContextImpl) context
                        .unwrap(HibernateConstraintValidatorContext.class);
                contextImpl.addExpressionVariable("invalidStr", s);
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```